# ExtJS Toggle button in the panel disappears after collapsing, Cannot expand it back

Tags: extjs4

I have a Ext.panel.Panel within a Tab Panel. Tab Panel is again within a window. I have set the following configs for Ext.panel.Panel

```
border : false,
collapsible : true,
collapseDirection : 'left',
width : 300,

layout : {
 type : 'vbox',
 align : 'stretch'
},
```

On clicking the Toggle button in the Ext.panel.Panel, it collapses, but the toggle button disappears which doesn't allow me to expand the collapsed panel again. On resizing the window, the toggle button appears back.

Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the solution given in this thread, http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?175371-Panel-Disappears-When-Collapsed.

> The main problem is that you have no layout declared for the panel which acts as your center region.

This also seems to be suggested by this thread http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?149446-Rendering-panel-collapsed-makes-it-disappear.